# Why does the plot interactivity (drag and zoom) stop working in this Python example?

Tags: python, matplotlib, format, widget, interactive

I am using `TextBox` from the module `matplotlib.widgets`. Basically, my code creates a plot with a text box where the user can input text to be printed on the console.

The issue is I can interactively drag and zoom in on the plot as long as I do not input any number in the text box. If I input a number, then the plot stops being interactive. The above does not happen if I enter letters. Please try it yourself with the code below.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.widgets as mwidgets 

# Data
x = np.arange(0,2*np.pi, 0.01)
y = np.sin(x)

# Plot
fig = plt.figure()
ax = plt.axes()
ax.plot(x, y)

# Ask for text input on the plot display
def submitText(text):
    print('Entered text = {}'.format(text))
axbox = plt.axes([0.3, 0.2, 0.3, 0.05])
text_box = mwidgets.TextBox(axbox, 'Write a text here: ', initial='{}'.format(text))
text_box.on_submit(submitText)


# Display plot
plt.show()
```

I really need to input numbers instead of letters and keep the interactive behavior of the plot. Does anyone know why this happens?

Any suggestion is welcome.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's essentially [this bug](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/issues/11432).

As a workaround:

1. Click the text field
2. type in your number
3. Click outside the text field
4. **Press the <kbd>a</kbd> key**
5. Activate zooming/panning etc.

Comment: I was afraid it is an actual bug and it could take a long time to be fixed. Thank you very much for the workaround!